# Unable to install Adhoc IPA file on my iPhone generated under visual studio

Tags: c#, iphone, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I was created a Xamarin PCL project for Android and iPhone in Visual Studio 2017.

**For Android:** The released APK file working fine.

**For iPhone:** I debugged in my iPhone with error free by connecting with my mac using of Xcode. Then finally the adhoc IPA file generated in Xcode for testing. I tried to install that IPA file in the same iPhone using iTunes but its start installing while it reaches 75% the installation terminates. 
Please help.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Comment: Yes i successfully installed.